# what is CSS background: background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across this today in the code I'm working on

```
.customeStyle {
   background: background
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what this means. it gives me a background color `purple`. so does that mean `background` means `purple` ? or does it means and do something else that I don't know of other than giving a purple background? I'm not English native speaker, so if `background` means `purple` then sorry for wasting your time.